# Android: External file in uiautomator

Tags: java, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have developed `mobile automation project` for android in java using uiautomator.

I have follow all the steps like :-

1. Create jar
2. Push jar to device
3. and at last run the test case

I need to automate the login functionality with `user name` and `password`. I have created excel file for reading usernames and password like `selenium`.

But when I access this Excel file, it gives File Not Found exception.

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest /sdcard/myApp.jar -c com.example.LoginTest
```

Is there any way to access other files in uiautomator ?

Answer (score 1):

`UIAutomator` runs inside the `shell` as a process, so we would not be able to access excel file which runs in PC

How ever, there are two ways you can automate it:

1.Write a Script to parse excel sheet and set them as dummy system properties, use UIAutomator to read the same

```
//set android dummy property using script
adb shell setprop dummy value 

//Read Value of property in UIAutomator
getProperty("dummy");

//Subroutine for Reading Property from Android
public String getProperty(String propName) {
String propValue = null;
try {
propValue = (String) Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties").getMethod("get", new Class[] { String.class }).invoke(null, propName);
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
return propValue;
}
```

2.Write values to a text file and parse it in Java in UIAutomator class

Comment: I m setting property by this command "adb shell setprop dummy value" but while getting this property it is giving blank or ""

Comment: is the device rooted? if yes, then try: adb shell -> su -> setprop dummy value

Comment: Device is not rooted.

Comment: Device should be rooted for SU level permissions